# DataTables individual search (text input) in specific columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

### Found a solution:

```
('#tabla_diccionarios tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    if(title=="Key" || title=="Nombre")
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" />' );
} );
```

### INITIAL POST

I need to have search in specific columns, image here:
[table header & search photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC2wB.png)

Only in columns named "Key" and "Nombre"

This is my code

```
var table = $('#tabla_diccionarios').DataTable( {
    "pagingType": "simple_numbers",
    "language": "json",
    "lengthMenu": [[-1, 10, 25, 50], ["Todos", 10, 25, 50]],
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar registros _MENU_ ",
        "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados.",
        "info": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de 
_TOTAL_ registros.",
        "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
        "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
        "paginate": {
            "previous": "Anterior",
            "next": "Siguiente",
        },
        "search": "Buscar: ",
    }
});

$('#tabla_diccionarios tfoot th').each( function () {
    /* var title = $(this).text(); */
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" />' );
} );

// Apply the search
table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;
    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
        if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
            that
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```

How can I do it, please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just figured it out:

```
('#tabla_diccionarios tfoot th').each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    if(title=="Key" || title=="Nombre")
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" />' );
} );
```